# using iptables to redirect a tcp service

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I am trying to setup a proxy to redirect a tcp service to a target server which I don't want it to be accessed directly by some people. Both proxy and target servers are on internet(not in my local network).

some clients -------> Proxy -------> Target Server (Allowed)

I ran the following script on the proxy server but it doesn't work.
I used tcpdump on the target server to see if it can recieve the packets, but it doesn't show up anything. So I guess the data is not sent out from the proxy.

Any sugession?

```
#!/bin/bash

iptables -F;iptables -t nat -F;

iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst ...
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --dst ...
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --dst ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.

just change the output to forward method.